# Python socket string returns different after sended

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to pass a string via socket using this code

```
p="YES"

s.send(p.encode())
---------------------
x = s.recv(10240).decode()

if x=="YES":
     print("YES")
```

Comment: Well, what *do* you receive, if it's not "YES"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a mistake in sending the message.
when you send a message your message should be sent in bytes

For example:
`s.send(bytes("Hello!", "utf-8))`

Here, `utf-8` is the encoding.

so in your case, the code should be as follows!

```py
#client.py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = "YOUR IP"
port = "YOUR PORT"

s.connect((ip,port))

p = "YES"

s.send(bytes(p, "utf-8"))
```

```py
#server.py

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = "0.0.0.0"#leave it as 0.0.0.0 as it will be read as localhost
port = "YOUR PORT"
s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen(10) #can accept upto 10 connections

while True:
   sc, address = s.accept()

   msg = sc.recv(1024)
   msg = msg.decode("utf-8")#since it was sent in utf-8 encoding, it has to be decoded from utf-8 only.
   print(msg)

   #or

   if msg == "YES":
      print("YES")
```

If this does not work or you have further queries, please ask!

Comment: This is nonsense, calling `.encode()` on a string is just another way to convert it to bytes.